# FCM Keep token in sync

Tags: android, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I using FCM with my Xamarin.Forms app. I'm a little confused on how can I maintain in sync the token generated in my app and the token stored in my app server.

Steps:

1. Open the app.
2. `OnTokenRefresh()`  get a new token.
3. The new token is send to the app server.
4. The app server sends push notifications.

This works perfect, except, that time to time, FCM destroy the token, the app is not running (step 2 not firing), so my app server can't send messages anymore, because is out of sync.

Is there a way to update the FCM token to my app server **without open the app**?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to remove tokens is when you try to use them to send a message. At that point the FCM API will tell you which tokens are invalid, and you can remove them fro your app server.

You can find an example of the code for this in the `functions-example` repo for [sending message through FCM](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/main/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js#L88-L108):

```
tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());
// Send notifications to all tokens.
const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
// For each message check if there was an error.
const tokensToRemove = [];
response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
  const error = result.error;
  if (error) {
    functions.logger.error(
      'Failure sending notification to',
      tokens[index],
      error
    );
    // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
    if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
        error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
      tokensToRemove.push(tokensSnapshot.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
    }
  }
});
return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
```

So for each token the server returns `messaging/invalid-registration-token` or `messaging/registration-token-not-registered` this code removes that token from its database.

Comment: Thanks Frank, but removing tokens from my app server is not the problem.
I already do that, I remove the token, but I can get a new one until the user open the app... So, if the user don't open the app, the token is not sending to my app server and the user won't get any new messages.

Comment: `OnTokenRefresh` should fire even when the app is not active, at least on Android, as it runs in a service.

Comment: Ok, so that should be the problem. I'll check!
Thanks Frank!